# Warning "Command \underbar has changed"

Tags: warnings

I am using the following code and I get the warning

```
Command \underbar has changed.
```

What does this mean? How do I fix it?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont
[
    UprightFont = *,
    BoldFont = *Bold,
    ItalicFont = *It,
    BoldItalicFont = *BoldIt,
    Extension = .otf,
    Ligatures = TeX,
    Mapping = tex-text
]{GFSArtemisia}


\setsansfont
[
    Mapping = tex-text
]{GFSArtemisia.otf}

\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}

\usepackage{sectsty}

\sectionfont{\RaggedRight}


\begin{document}

Text

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's caused by `sectsty`. You can load that earlier to avoid that particular warning.

Comment: $$\underbar$$ why doesn't it work here? is it possible to put it in math exchange somehow?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The warning is caused by a check `sectsty` runs on the definition of `\underbar`. If it doesn't match one of the definitions it expects, it warns you.

You can avoid this warning ***but I don't recommend it***. The warning is telling you something important: that `sectsty` has found a definition of `\underbar` which is not what it expects and that things may not work properly.

In truth, I would recommend not using `sectsty` with LuaTeX/XeTeX. In particular, I wouldn't use it with `unicode-math`.

If you insist, for LuaTeX, you can avoid that particular warning by loading the package earlier. For XeTeX, you can avoid that warning by loading the package earlier.

For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont
[
    UprightFont = *,
    BoldFont = *Bold,
    ItalicFont = *It,
    BoldItalicFont = *BoldIt,
    Extension = .otf,
    Ligatures = TeX,
]{GFSArtemisia}
\setsansfont
[
    Ligatures = TeX,
]{GFSArtemisia.otf}
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}
\sectionfont{\RaggedRight}
\begin{document}

Text

\end{document}
```

However, I get other warnings with LuaTeX.

Comment: Thank you but before which packages must generally be loaded?

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry, but I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: You said I must load it earlier. Earlier than which package?

Comment: I'm not sure. It doesn't know about the new font handling stuff. Probably when to load it depends on the result you want. That is, how do you want the definition of `\underbar` to end up at the end of the preamble? If you load it after `unicode-math`, you'll get a warning because `unicode-math` redefines `\underbar`. But the real question is: do you want `sectsty`'s or `unicode-math`'s or something else?

Comment: Please see edit.

Comment: $$\underbar$$ why doesn't it work here? is it possible to put it in math exchange somehow?

Comment: @CharlieParker What do you mean?

Comment: Why shouldn't we use `\sectsy` with LuaTeX? What alternatives should we use?

Comment: I use sectsty because it is only way I could color my section headings.  Is there an alternative way to adjust color of section headings that you suggest instead.  I agree with general advice not to use sectsty, but cannot find alternative.

Comment: @It'sNotALie. Well, for the reasons explained in my answer?

Comment: @pauljohn32 I just redefine what I need, but lots of people like `titlesec`. I can't get on with it at all. Whatever I've tried to do with it has turned out to be easier without, but everyone else gets on great with it. So, if you aren't me, you might try that.

Comment: Loading the package earlier does not remove the warning for me, in Lualatex

Answer (score 12):

You have really nothing to worry about, provided you don't use `sectsty` for *underlining* section titles.

The package does a check on `\underbar` and on `\underline`, because it wants to redefine them but it just does so when typesetting those titles.

So, if you don't use underlining (and you're better not to), there should be no problem.

Something actually can be done to fully disable those redefinitions (only risky if you happen to use `\underbar` in a section title, actually).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[immediate]{silence}
\WarningFilter[temp]{latex}{Command} % silence the warning
\usepackage{sectsty}
\DeactivateWarningFilters[temp] % So nothing unrelated gets silenced

\makeatletter % disable the runtime redefinitions
\let\SS@makeulinesect\relax
\let\SS@makeulinepartchap\relax
\makeatother

\setmainfont[
    UprightFont = *,
    BoldFont = *Bold,
    ItalicFont = *It,
    BoldItalicFont = *BoldIt,
    Extension = .otf,
    Ligatures = TeX,
]{GFSArtemisia}
\setsansfont{GFSArtemisia.otf}
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}

\sectionfont{\RaggedRight}


\begin{document}

Text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, it boils down to `\usepackage{silence}` and then `\WarningFilter{latex}{Command}` in the preamble. Maybe not recommended to do by default ;)

Comment: @TomaszGandor Until the package author/maintainer decides to update it, one has to live with the warning (or silence it).

Comment: You can be even more specific with `\WarningFilter[temp]{latex}{Command \underbar  has changed.}
\WarningFilter[temp]{latex}{Command \underline  has changed.} `