# hyperref.sty error fixed, now catchfile.sty error

Tags: hyperref, texlive-2019

I have the following code to generate an article with LaTeX. I am using TexStudio with macOS Catalina. This code was working until today when I updated all the packages loaded within TeX Live Utility app.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1.3in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{brilliantrose}{rgb}{1.0,0.33,0.64}
\usepackage[breaklinks=true, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=CornflowerBlue, urlcolor=cyan, citecolor=RoyalBlue]{hyperref}
\sectionfont{\color{RoyalBlue}}
\subsectionfont{\color{RoyalBlue}}
\subsubsectionfont{\color{RoyalBlue}}

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,angles,quotes}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\usepackage{esvect}

\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{empheq}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} 
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = {\,}]
\cal{cal}
\DeclareSIUnit\kcal{\kilo\cal}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\newcolumntype{a}{>{\columncolor{CornflowerBlue}}c}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[backend=biber, sorting=none, maxnames=35]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{script.bib}

\title{Symmetry}

\date{\today}

\begin{document}

    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents

Hello

\end{document}
```

I get the following error:

```
File `ltxcmds.sty' not found. \RequirePackage{ltxcmds}[2010/11/12]
```

This error is in line 105 of hyperref.sty.

I also get the following warning

```
Command \underbar has changed
```

which is in sectsty.sty. I moved `\usepackage{sectsty}` higher as I read in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/310968/181898) answer that this package needs to be loaded before some others (not very helpful).

The log file is here:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.1.9)  9 JAN 2020 22:45
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**main.tex
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 3
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/10/25 v1.4k Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2019/10/25 v1.4k Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/sectsty/sectsty.sty
Package: sectsty 2002/02/25 v2.0.2 Commands to change all sectional heading sty
les


LaTeX Warning: Command \underbar  has changed.
               Check if current package is valid.


LaTeX Warning: Command \underline  has changed.
               Check if current package is valid.

) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2018/08/11 v1.3c Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks14
\inpenc@posthook=\toks15
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2019/11/07 v1.0c TeX engine tests
))
\Gm@cnth=\count88
\Gm@cntv=\count89
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count90
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen103
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen104
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen105
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen106
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen107
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen108
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen109
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen110
\Gm@dimlist=\toks17
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/titlesec.sty
Package: titlesec 2019/10/16 v2.13 Sectioning titles
\ttl@box=\box27
\beforetitleunit=\skip43
\aftertitleunit=\skip44
\ttl@plus=\dimen111
\ttl@minus=\dimen112
\ttl@toksa=\toks18
\titlewidth=\dimen113
\titlewidthlast=\dimen114
\titlewidthfirst=\dimen115
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/colortbl/colortbl.sty
Package: colortbl 2018/12/12 v1.0d Color table columns (DPC)

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty
Package: array 2019/08/31 v2.4l Tabular extension package (FMi)
\col@sep=\dimen116
\ar@mcellbox=\box28
\extrarowheight=\dimen117
\NC@list=\toks19
\extratabsurround=\skip45
\backup@length=\skip46
\ar@cellbox=\box29
)
\everycr=\toks20
\minrowclearance=\skip47
)
\rownum=\count91
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvipsnam.def
File: dvipsnam.def 2016/06/17 v3.0m Driver-dependent file (DPC,SPQR)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2019/11/10 v7.00c Hypertext links for LaTeX


! LaTeX Error: File `ltxcmds.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.105 \RequirePackage{ltxcmds}[2010/11/12]
                                          ^^M
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1978 strings out of 492163
 25732 string characters out of 6125307
 106503 words of memory out of 5000000
 6383 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 32i,0n,37p,229b,36s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

**EDIT**

The problem with hyperref.sty is solved after tlmgr update as suggested in comments. Now when I try to compile it I get the following error in line 157 of catchfile.sty

```
File `infwarerr.sty' not found. \RequirePackage{infwarerr}[2007/09/09]
```

and the following lines appear in the log file:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `infwarerr.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.157   \RequirePackage{infwarerr}[2007/09/09]
                                              %^^M
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)
```

Comment: You might want to start by moving `hyperref` to its correct position as the last package of teh preamble. Without a few excaptions, `hyperref` should be the last package that you load.

Comment: @leandriis it didn't work, and I pretty much use the same intro in all my TeX files and they all work in this order.

Comment: you need to install `ltxcmds`  a command such as `tlmgr install ltxcmds` should work, or `tlmgr update --all` to update everything

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for the help. I tried `tlmgr update --all` but I got the error `the directory /usr/local/texlive/2019/tlpkg/ is not writable.
Please run this program as administrator, or contact your local admin.` which is very weird because I am the admin...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I managed to make it work with `sudo`.

Comment: in that case you presumably need `sudo tlmgr update --all` (which most likely means that you originally installed under sudo) although actually I just noticed you said `I updated all the packages loaded within TeX Live Utility app.`  that will be a wrapper for tlmgr so you shoul dbe able to install ltxcmds using the same

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the problem with hyperref.sty is fixed, thanks. I updated the question as I still cannot compile, any suggestions on that?

Comment: exactly the same, install the missing package infwarerr

Comment: well do the same only with another package: install infwarerr,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle so everything was working until today. what might have happened to break everything?

Comment: the oberdiek bundle of 100 packages has been re-organised and some packages are distributed separately. Most people set texlive to install all packages and a simple update will be all that needed , but if you installed a subset you may need to adjust the subset that you install.