# \underline and \underbar commands have change warning

Tags: warnings, underline

I have two warnings telling me that "Command \underbar has changed." and "Command \underline has changed." but I don't get why is that so since I am not using these commands.

I have seen an explanation in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310965/warning-command-underbar-has-changed) but I am not using the package sectsty. Any help wuld be wellcome.

Below  I am leaving a sample code of my preamble.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,
    amsmath,
    amsfonts,
    eurosym,
    geometry,
    ulem,
    graphicx,
    caption,
    color,
    setspace,
    sectsty,
    comment,
    footmisc,
    caption,
    % natbib,
    %biblatex,
    pdflscape,
    array,
    hyperref
}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

% Package for drawings
\usepackage{tikz}

% Package for subcaption
\usepackage{subcaption}

% Options for biblatex package
\usepackage[
    backend = biber,
    bibencoding = latin1,
    style = authoryear,
    natbib,
]
{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Biblio/bib.bib}
\normalem

\onehalfspacing
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newenvironment{proof}[1][Proof]{\noindent\textbf{#1.} }{\ \rule{0.5em}{0.5em}}

\newtheorem{hyp}{Hypothesis}
\newtheorem{subhyp}{Hypothesis}[hyp]
\renewcommand{\thesubhyp}{\thehyp\alph{subhyp}}

\newcommand{\red}[1]{{\color{red} #1}}
\newcommand{\blue}[1]{{\color{blue} #1}}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\geometry{left=1.0in,right=1.0in,top=1.0in,bottom=1.0in}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The package `sectsty`, for some reasons, checks that the meaning of `\underline` and `\underbar` haven't changed from the kernel version; the kernel definition of those commands *has* changed, but the author of the package didn't update them. You *are* loading `sectsty`, by the way: this is what triggers the warnings. If you're not using its features, why do you load it?

Comment: `\underline` is TeX primitive. But if someone is using LaTeX then he/she can't be sure of anything:).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I was using a template and I took for granted that sectsty wasn't uploaded, I have removed it and now no warning appears. Thank you very much for your time