# Command \underbar has changed

Tags: warnings

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{sectsty}
% \usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=20mm,bottom=20mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=20mm,bottom=20mm,left=20mm,right=20mm]{geometry}  % width=210mm, height=297mm,

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.369}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{textcmds}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

 % create the groups
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
  \item[\bfseries
  \ifstrequal{#1}{G}{General notation}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{N}{Neural networks}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{P}{Probability and statistics}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{L}{Natural language processing}{}}}}%
]}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\graphicspath{{images/}}


\chapterfont{\Large}
\sectionfont{\large}
\subsectionfont{\normalsize}
\subsubsectionfont{\normalsize}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
% \usepackage{hyperref}
% \hypersetup{
%   colorlinks   = true, %Colours links instead of ugly boxes
%   urlcolor     = teal, %Colour for external hyperlinks
%   linkcolor    = blue, %Colour of internal links
%   citecolor   = red %Colour of citations
% }

\usepackage{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{{#1\adddot}}
% \usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
% \usepackage[style=authoryear, sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
\input{titlepage.tex}
\input{russiantitlepage.tex}

\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage



% ===================================================================================
\chapter*{Abstract}
bla bla
% ===================================================================================


% ===================================================================================
\chapter*{Acknowledgments}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgments}


% ===================================================================================
\chapter{Conclusions}
% ===================================================================================

bla bla

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\begin{sloppypar}
% \printbibliography
\end{sloppypar}

\end{document}
```

I am using the above template but still getting the warning, I have tried this solution but the issue still exists.[Warning "Command \underbar has changed"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310965/warning-command-underbar-has-changed)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warning "Command \underbar has changed"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310965/warning-command-underbar-has-changed) If I apply my suggestion with `silence`, the warning disappears.

Comment: i have add these two lines \usepackage[immediate]{silence}
\WarningFilter[temp]{latex}{Command}  the   nothing changed